# How to locate the "grab-handle" on the address bar for Chrome 5?

Tags: google-chrome, address-bar

I just read this on a forum:

Chrome 5 has a **grab-handle** on the address bar, so you can adjust the width allocated to the extension icons and force them into a drop-down menu **(indicated by a >> symbol**).

Answer (score 0):

It's not specially marked, but the draggable area is the rightmost border of the address field, plus a few px to the right.

[image]

The "»" symbol is *not* the grab-handle, it's the overflow indicator which only appears *after* the icon area has been shrunk. Also, it has been removed from the latest Chrome version – icons now overflow into the main menu instead.

Comment: [Here, have a gif :D](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7VDUO.gif).

Comment: Thank you both for the very quick response to my question.

Comment: I may have not specifically asked it correctly - I would like to add 1 or possibly 2 more lines of the address field.

Comment: @MarthaMcKnight That’s not going to happen. If you need a customizable GUI, there’s virtually no other option but to use Firefox.

Comment: Hey "grawity".  I do not know what happened to my last (second) entry, but please excuse me because I am knew.  I noticed that the other person who had a comment/suggestion just removed their answer. Of course, I do not know why, but anyway . . .I just want to be able to have more than one line of icons.  Any ideas how to get around the v.5 change?  THANK!!!

Comment: Thanks Daniel B. - I thought you had left or removed the gif, which I wanted to save.  Thanks for sending it.  Do you use Firefox?

Comment: I absolutely HATE typing errors.  I meant that I "new", NOT "knew".